# SQL Developer Commit

Tags: sql, oracle, time, oracle-sqldeveloper, commit

I'm using Oracle SQL Developer tool, version 3.0.02 and I'm having some trouble understanding the following: if I Commit an update and the time response is '0 seconds' the commit is done properly? Because it happened a few times and the DB wasn't updated. I don't know if it's a coincidence or not. When I commit for the second time(just to be sure) after it shows me '0 seconds', it appears '0,016 seconds' and the update shows correctly. But I don't wanna commit 4 times in a row just to get it right. What do you guys think about this? Oh and it doesn't give me no errors.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Clarification can only come with some code.

Comment: UPDATE db SET user='name' where file='name_of_file' and answer='okay'

Comment: It doesn't matter, I run the update and then when I commit it appears like I said '0 seconds'

Comment: the code from the update script is correct, because in most of the cases it works, but when it fails, the only thing that I noticed is this time of response changing. I mean, to me it seems logical that if it shows all the time '0,032' or so, it should all the time give me some numbers even if it's almost instantaneous. When it appears '0 seconds' the DB is not updated.

Comment: thank you though, for trying to help me :)

Comment: if you're using the COMMIT button, you will see a COMMIT SUCCESSFUL (or not) message in the log panel, example: "Import-export_peeps2-csv-bad.sql*: Thu Apr 30 13:24:05 EDT 2015: Commit successful"  Also, version 3.0 is old, upgrade to version 4.0.3 for a better overall experience.

Answer (score 2):

The time taken by commit has nothing to do with any malfunctioning. The work is done by the query and commit just notes somewhere in the metadata that the transaction is finished. Commit does almost anything(just force to save on the disk some log files). If something gets wrong (i.e. commit don't work) you'll get an error. 
The absence of the error signals that everything is ok, the database has done all you have asked to it.

For example, your updates may do nothing:

```
UPDATE db SET user='name' where file='name_of_file' and answer='okay' ;
```

if there is no file named 'name_of_the_file' with answer = 'okay' the database will do no work. And nothing to commit.

For the sake of a complete answer i'll add these points from this [blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/prajkumar/entry/sql_transaction_control_language_commands):

> When a transaction is committed, the following occurs:
>
> 1. The internal transaction table for the associated undo table space records that the transaction has committed, and the
>      corresponding unique system change number (SCN) of the transaction is
>      assigned and recorded in the table
> 2. The log writer process (LGWR) writes redo log entries in the SGA's redo log buffers to the redo log file. It also writes the
>      transaction's SCN to the redo log file. This atomic event constitutes
>      the commit of the transaction
> 3. Oracle releases locks held on rows and tables
> 4. Oracle marks the transaction complete

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful! I do have all the data correct, all the rows are updated, the commit doesn't give me any error(I always commit the changes), but I was informed by my superiors that for some of them the update hasn't been made (it doesn't appear to them) and I was curious why. Where's the glich..

Comment: "it doesn't appear to them". They appear to you? If not, make sure yo've done what you think you've done. If yes, then make sure you have commited the transaction and ask them them to rerun the query after commit. A query started before your commit, will see old data.

Comment: Yes, it appears to me, but to them it doesn't. I even check every time after I make a commit if the data was updated correctly. That's the weird stuff I was talking about, and that's why I ended up asking a stupid question.. last resort :)

Answer (score 1):

You can check Oracle documentation to learn why `commit` is such a fast operation (`rollback` takes *much* longer, it has to refer to undo segments). 
'Lost' commits may happen if somebody else commits their data, which appears to be the same as the 'old' data for you.

Comment: Thank you :) I understood. The problem is nobody else is using commit on the data that I work on, still it happens and it's frustrating